# Header has 2 rows on the mobile

Tags: html, css

I got this but I don't know why when I open it on mobile phone "Where to" is split into 2 rows. But when I open Chrome Developer tools it's ok even with the minimum width of the page.

```css
 /*Column*/
    .header {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 55%);
        width: fit-content;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    
    }
    #column {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 33%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .columnNad {
        color: #ff6347;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .columnText {
        color: #000;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">Where to</div>
    <div id="column">
      <div class="columnNad">TEST</div>
      <div class="columnText">Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123<br><br></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I wanted to add a snippet but it said it's not formatted and couldn't post it... Even when I entered all code in the right columns. So sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.header`.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

#column {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.columnNad {
  color: #ff6347;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.columnText {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Where to</div>
<div id="column">
  <div class="columnNad">TEST</div>
  <div class="columnText">Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123<br><br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `width: fit-content; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` from header and add `text-align: center;` like below:

```
.header {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the message but then is the shadow with full width.